# How is method group overload resolution different to method call overload resolution?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, covariance, overloading

The following code doesn't compile (`error CS0123: No overload for 'System.Convert.ToString(object)' matches delegate 'System.Converter<T,string>'`):

```
class A<T> {
    void Method(T obj) {
        Converter<T, string> toString = Convert.ToString;

        // this doesn't work either (on .NET 4):
        Converter<object, string> toString2 = Convert.ToString;
        Converter<T, string> toString3 = toString2;            
    }
}
```

however, this does:

```
class A<T> {
    void Method(T obj) {
        // o is a T, and Convert.ToString(o) is using
        // string Convert.ToString(object o)

        Converter<T, string> toString = o => Convert.ToString(o);
    }
}
```

In c# 4, co/contra-variant delegates can be assigned to each other, and delegates can be created from co/contra-variant methods, so the `ToString(object)` method can be used as a `Converter<T, string>`, as `T` is always guarenteed to be convertable to an `object`.

So, the first example (method group overload resolution) should be finding the only applicable method `string Convert.ToString(object o)`, the same as the method call overload resolution. Why is the method group & method call overload resolution producing different results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with the fact that variance is not applicable to value types, so if you restrict `T` like `where T : class` you get variance on `T` and the first snippet of code will compile.

From the [Covariance and Contravariance FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/csharpfaq/covariance-and-contravariance-faq):

> Variance is supported only if a type
> parameter is a reference type.
> Variance is not supported for value
> types.

Comment: More specifically, it's doesn't work for an unconstrained `T` because it _might be_ a value type.

Answer (score 0):

The second code compiles because `o` *derives* from `object`, so obviously you can invoke a method that takes an `object` as input with *any* type of parameter.

The delegate types, however, are *not equal*. Unless `T` is `object` the method signatures don't match. If, say, `T` is `int` you would have a `Converter<int, string>` which is not the same as `Converter<object, string`. They are two entirely **different types**.

You are hitting the issues around C# 3.0's lack of co/contra-variance. Should be better in C# 4.